# Started receiving 429 Too Many Requests from Google Calendar API

Tags: google-calendar-api

Yesterday (June 22nd, 2020)  at 2pm Pacific, we started getting back 429 errors for all our requests to the Google Calendar V3 API.   The body returned is html that asks the user to fill out a captcha.

These errors are not the standard 403 errors you get when you hit Google Calendar quota limits.  Also, we checked, and we haven't hit Google Calendar API limits.  So I assume this rate limiting is happening at a different level.

We fixed the issue yesterday by changing the IP address that we are sending these requests from.  Unfortunately, again at 2pm today (June 23rd, 2020) the problem started happening again.

We are not getting these errors back from the Google Address Book API.  It just seems to be Google Calendar API.

Has anyone else noticed 429 errors from Google Calendar API over the last few days?  Or is Google listening and might be able to help?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm seeing similar behavior for our app that started during a similar timeframe. I don't see any errors in the google cloud console to indicate what's happening.

Comment: Please edit your question include your code and the full error message there are a lot of 429 errors we need to know which one it is you are hitting, we need to see how you are authenticating.  We need to know what language you are using.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### There seems to be a new issue that has been [filed](https://issuetracker.google.com/159368649) on June 19th on Google's Public Issue Tracker

Seems like several users are affected, but the issue is reported to be currently investigated.

I recommend you to "star" the issue in order to stay up to date to its current state.

In the meantime, since the 429 error seems to be related to `rateLimitExceeded`, you can try to workaround in the same way like for [403 errors](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/errors?hl=en#403_user_rate_limit_exceeded), that is e.g. implement exponential backoff as described in the documentation.

Comment: A month later: the issue is still open and it seems there was a spike in occurrences today, based on the # of posts in the issue's thread in the past 24 hours.

Answer (score 2):

I had had the same issue with Google Calendar API today. HTTP Code 426 and HTML page with captcha in the response body.
[This decision](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/159368649#comment41) had helped me

If you use python you need to replace

```
build('calendar', 'v3', http=creds.authorize(Http()))
```

with:

```
DISCOVERY_DOC = json.load(open(os.path.join(SCRIPT_DIR, 'calendar-api.json')))
googleapiclient.discovery.build_from_document(DISCOVERY_DOC,http=creds.authorize(Http()))
```

calendar-api.json you can download from this [link](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/googleapis/google-api-go-client/master/calendar/v3/calendar-api.json)